# How to change the Text of Custom field in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I've created a custom Field subclass, with image and text. How do I change the text of that field at runtime? Is there any method to change the text of that field?

Answer (score 2):

If you wrote your own Field object, then you have to handle it yourself.   How are the text and image drawn on screen?  If you have your own paint method, you should already be storing the text as a String object in a member variable of the Field object.

Changing the text on screen is a matter of updating that String, and then calling Field.invalidate() to force a redraw.